# How are large APIs updated so frequently?

Tags: api

I was looking at the pga tour scoreboard from a google search and I think I found the api server that the pga tour gets all their scoring information from.

The file with their endpoints for just one tournament was massive, like 9,000 lines of JSON. How do they reflect scoring changes in real time so fans can track a certain players performance? Does a person have to manually update api endpoints so that they can display up to date information? Did it all originate from a csv file or something?

Comment: Usually people assisted with computers enter things in a database as they happen. The API just reads this database.

Comment: That’s a lot of information and people to keep track of. Very interesting.